# How can I get my div id to reload via ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic, html

I'm creating a CMS using jQuery and AJAX. When I click, my "Add Campaign" buttom, it creates a unique client ID in the DB and on a hard reload, the new client shows up in its container.  I am trying to use ajax to reload the container on the fly and I'm not having the exact luck i am hoping for.  I can get it to reload, but it's like it's pulling in descriptions of each of the clients as well!

function AddNewClient() {

dataToLoad = 'clientID=' + clientID + '&addClient=yes';

$.ajax({
 type: 'post', 
 url: '/clients/controller.php',
 datatype: 'html',
 data: dataToLoad,
 target: ('#clientssidebar'),
 async: false,
 success: function(html){
  $('#clientssidebar').html(html);
  },
 error: function() {
 alert('An error occured!');
 }
 });

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function AddNewClient() 
{
    dataToLoad = 'clientID=' + clientID + '&addClient=yes';
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'post', 
        url: '/clients/controller.php', 
        data: dataToLoad, 
        success: function(html){ 
            $('#clientssidebar').html(html); }, 
        error: function() { 
            alert('An error occured!'); } 
        });
}
```

Comment: I am ending up with the same problem still, will edit regular post with link so you can see. thank you for trying!

Comment: I followed your link and apparently it does what I think it should be doing. Could you elaborate on what you want it to do exactly?

Comment: It's adding the new client, but as you can see when it reloads, it is pulling in information that should be going inside of a div once one of those individual campaigns are clicked, when really, just the lorem ipsum should be pulled up..

Comment: That's probably a matter of how the response is formed. Look inside your `/clients/controller.php`, it probably sends out the data you wish not pull.

Comment: Found out the problem, you were right...   In the php page, in the loop it was echoing out all of that additional data.  
Thanks!